# Pushgateway throws 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: basic-authentication, bcrypt, prometheus-pushgateway

I am trying to push metrics towards basic auth authenticated Push Gateway. But I am running into 401 - Unauthorized

So I installed a local push gateway and configured it with basic authentication:

The password is encrypted as described here : https://github.com/prometheus/exporter-toolkit/blob/master/docs/web-configuration.md#about-bcrypt

```
basic_auth_users:
  pushgateway: $2y$10$d6t8zGfPMZBLFLpoClFcReK6z4gxkDr2H8jnEfOaUpjpLX4.tbyTS%
```

In my code, I specify the username and password as follows:

```
this.pushGateway.setConnectionFactory(new BasicAuthHttpConnectionFactory("pushgateway","<password>"));
```

The password above is the one that was encrypted and put into push gateway config.

The documentation here (https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#with-basic-auth) does not mention anything about encrypting the password, the password is provided in plaintext.

Can someone please point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation you outlined, the bcrypt procedure only applies to exporters using the exporter-toolkit while the Java client takes the parameter in plain text.

The reason behind that is that bcrypt is designed for password storage. bcrypt internally generates a salt for you and various information needed to recompute the hash from the plain text.

The information are separated by `$` and salt is the 22 first char of the hash; in your example:

- `2y` is the BCrypt algorithm version
- `10` is the strength of the algorithm
- `d6t8zGfPMZBLFLpoClFcRe` is the salt
- remainder is the hash

When authenticating to the exporter, basic-auth will send the password in plain text and bcrypt can be used to validate it on the server side.

If you were to send it hashed from the client, the exporter (server) would not know how to recover the plaintext password (it is a hash, not an encryption).

If the secret is leaked on the server side, the salt (supposedly) ensures that the password is hard to recover. On the client side, you are responsible for making sure the plain password is not leaked.